# Need help installing openpyxl - Solved

Tags: excel, pip, openpyxl

I keep getting this error:

```
**WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/openpyxl/**
**Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/openpyxl/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/openpyxl/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer **
certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))) - skipping
**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openpyxl (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for openpyxl**
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the 
ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))) - skipping
**WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.**
```

I'm using Visual Studios and want to use python to automated excel but can get past this first step XD

I've tried installing/updating pip and uninstalling/reinstalling python 3.11.1 but don't know what else to try

Comment: Are you using a proxy to access the internet? If so you may not have configured it in VS

Comment: That fixed the issue! I have an authentication proxy on my home computer for work that was interfering and pausing that solved the problem :)